# Passing Child Builders

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I have a case where I have something like:

```
public abstract class Base{    
   private Base sibling;

   public Base( Base sibling ){
         this.sibling = sibling;
   }

   public Base getSibling(){
       return this.sibling;
   }
}

public class ChildA extends Base{
      private ChildB brother;

      public ChildA(){
          this.brother = new ChildB( this );
      }

      public ChildB getBrother(){ return this.brother }
      public void methodA(){ ... }
      public void methodB(){ ... }

}

public class ChildB extends Base{
   public childB someMethodX(){ ... }
   public childB someMethodY(){ ... }
}
```

Now I need it so that when doing something like:

```
   var child = new ChildA()
       .getBrother()
           .someMethodX()
           .someMethodY()
           .getSibling()
       .methodA()
       .methodB()
```

`.getSibling()` returns me back into the scope of `ChildA`. Currently however it seems to be returning me an instance of `Base` and giving me an error that `methodA()` does not exist in class `Base`.

I've looked at some cases of GenericTypes as possibly being what I want in this case, but I've struggled to implement it as of yet. Any examples/pointers/links would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to cast to ChildA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because `methodA` is defined in `ChildA` but `getSibling` returns `Base` reference. Although this `Base` reference happens to point to `ChildA` object, you should either perform explicit castings or generalize `Base` type.

In this particular case, you may simply override `getSibling`:

```
class ChildB extends Base {
  public ChildB(ChildA sibling) {
    super(sibling);
  }

  @Override
  public ChildA getSibling() {
    return (ChildA) super.getSibling();
  }
}
```

This would not scale well if there are a lot of classes like `ChildB` though. Also, `ChildB` is restricted to contain only `ChildA` as it's sibling.

---

*Edit:*

> it may not always be childB

Alright, assuming you don't need `Base` class to be generic, you may replace it with:

```
class ChildB <T extends Base> extends Base {
    public ChildB(T sibling) {
      super(sibling);
    }


    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getSibling() {
      return (T) super.getSibling();
    }
}
```

You may instantiate it as follows:

```
brother = new ChildB<ChildA>(this);
```

Comment: Problem with this solution for my case is that ChildB may be included in other subclasses of Base, so getSibling should return those. i.e, it may not always be childB

Comment: Okay, what about second option?

Answer (score 1):

Unless by casting, you can't do what you want:

```
  var child = new ChildA()
       .getBrother() // ChildB 
           .someMethodX() // void
           .someMethodY() // compile error
           .getSibling()  // compile error (someMethodY = void), Base
       .methodA() // compile error, methodA does not exists on Base
       .methodB() // idem.
```

I propose you two methods to doing that:

- a generic type on `Base`, so that `Base` can return `this` as the subtype rather than `Base`. If `ChildA` extends `Base`, with two methods `ChildA::setFoobar`, `Base::setSaxon`, then doing: `builder.setSaxon("A").setFoobar("B")` would be possible due to the generic.

  ```
  public class Base<B extends Base<B>> {
    protected abstract B self();
    public <C extends Base<C>> B setSibling(Base<C> base) {
      this.sibling = base;
      return self(); // or (B)this
    }
  }    
  public class ChildA extends Base<ChildA> {
    protected ChildA self() {return this;}
  }
  public class ChildB extends Base<ChildB> {}
  ```

  And this would work:

  ```
  ChildA a = new ChildA().setSibling(new ChildB().setSibling(new ChildA()));
  ```

  The `self` method will avoid a cast to `(B)this` in each `setXXX` method.
- using a builder wrapper for B: return an intermediate object `ChildBBuilder`, whose "final" method `getSibling()` associated a new instance of `ChildB` to the `ChildA` it belongs, and return that object to continue the chain:

  ```
  public class ChildA extends Base{
    private ChildB brother;
    public ChildBBuilder getBrother() {
      return new ChildBBuilder() {
        public ChildA getSibling() {
          ChildA.this.brother = create();
          return ChildA.this;
        }
      };
    }
  }

  public class ChildBBuilder {
    public ChildBBuilder(ChildA parent) {
      this.parent = parent;
    }
    ... setter ...

    public ChildB create() {
      return new ChildB();
    }

    public ChildA getSibling() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
  }
  ```

  `ChildBBuilder` is an independant builder allowing some getSibling operation whose default implementation is to fail. We create an anonymous abstract class to handle this case.

I already used in some of my project the first case, with the "base builder".

For the second case, I never used it. If you are trying to create a DSL for some of your work, don't forget it might be too much for what it's worth even if it's nice and all.

If you are working with Java 8 you can extends the pattern to a pure abstract implementation: [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936150/how-to-implement-a-builder-class-using-generics-not-annotations/24939058#24939058).